# Running Artisan commands (migrations) outside Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently i'm running db migrations from commandline like so :

```
> php artisan migrate:make foo --create:footable

> php artisan migrate
```

But how can i run Laravel 4 migrations from a non-Laravel script? Instead of the usual artisan migarte commands, or even the `Artisan::call()` instruction.

Just to clarify, i need to run already created migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 4.1+, the following does not work:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('option' => '--bench', 'argument' => 'vendor/package'))
Throws : The "option" argument does not exist.

Artisan::call('migrate --package=vendor/package');
Throws : Command "migrate --bench=vendor/package" is not defined
```

But this does:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--bench'=>'vendor/package'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to boot your a Laravel application by doing:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'bootstrap/start.php';
```

Then you will have access to the `$app` global variable, which holds the whole Laravel application, including Artisan, so you'll be able to:

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

and

```
$app['artisan']->call('migrate');
```

If you have an external namespaced class, like this one:

```
<?php namespace App\Example; 

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
require 'bootstrap/start.php'; 

use Form;
use Artisan;

class Example { 

    public function make() { 

        Artisan::call('migrate');

    } `enter code here`

}
```

You can call it using:

```
<?php

require 'Example.php';

use App\Example\Example;

$s = new Example;

dd($s->make());
```

This is not advisable, but as a last resort, you can use:

```
return $GLOBALS['app']['artisan']->call('migrate');
```

Comment: i cannot run cmd while the package is being initialized in an app. i want to automate the migration through code

Comment: actually i needed to know if there is some global App object that i can access to call all the laravel class inside a package class. And `Artisan::call()` does not work there also

Comment: You should give us some examples of what you are doing exactly, what kind of package you are developing, how this package is structured, so we can have something to work with. Edited to give you some options.

Comment: i see you get my point. but `$this->app['artisan']` is not available in other class. How do i get it there? I cannot access it through namespace resolution like `\Artisan::call()' like i do with DB or Auth. Why is that?

Comment: `$this->app['artisan']` works in provider. but what do i have to put in my other class which is in the same directory as the provider. the other class im talking about does not have any access to laravel objects directly. Whats the namespace i use to acess it there. sorry i had to write all this into comments

Comment: the package is just for practice to know how it all works and if i were to integrate an external class how would i actually do it.

Comment: As I said, you'll have to boot Laravel to have access to the `$app` global variable. Edited to show how.

Comment: thats right too. but why does the namespace not work? can't i access it through namespace resolution like with the other components?

Comment: Yeah, just tested here and you will be able to use `Artisan::call()` if is that what you mean by `namespace resolution`, which is not exactly that. Namespace resolution is done by Composer, not Laravel, so `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` is the guy responsible for loading up all namespaces and if you need to do things like ´$u = new Models\User´ it will now work too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52758/discussion-between-hussain-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro)